# How to find index of clickable element on delegation?

Tags: javascript, mustache

How can I find index of clickable element? I would need to get the index of `li` when its button was clicked, so I can delete it from array.

```
    var template = document.querySelector('#template');
    this.element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON' && e.target.className == 'remove') {
            //var index = ??
            //this.deleteTask(index);
        }
    }.bind(this));


    <script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
        <ul>
            {{ #tasks }}
                <li>{{ . }} - <button class="remove">X</button></li>
            {{ /tasks }}
        </ul>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `@index`, you can attach it to the button itself with a data attribute, and then use that:

```
var template = document.querySelector('#template');
this.element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON' && e.target.className == 'remove') {
        var index = e.target.dataset.index;
        // or possibly e.target.getAttribute('data-index');
        this.deleteTask(parseInt(index, 10));
    }
}.bind(this));


<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    <ul>
        {{ #tasks }}
            <li>{{ . }} - <button class="remove" data-index="{{ @index }}">X</button></li>
        {{ /tasks }}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: Should this @index work out of the box? I can see there is empty data-index on button when inspecting element in devTools so on button click there is nothing on e.target.dataset.

Comment: are you using `handlebars`? or `mustache` itself?

Comment: I don't think mustache itself has any way of accessing the index. `@index` should be available when using handlebars, but in mustache you'll need to use something else, like a `key` property on your item or something similar.

Comment: Adding to what @rossipedia mentioned, if you are using Mustache, You would add `data["index"] = function () { return index++; }` and `index` would be initialized to `var index = 1;`